# React app, change application context at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tomcat, deployment, tomcat7

Using create-react-app I have an application that runs within a .war which is deployed on tomcat. My question is as follows,

http://ip_addr:port/my_application_context/

I need to be able to set the ip_addr:port/my_application_context, variable to whatever I want, at runtime, in production because all of our customers use different paths.

Right now I can use a .env.production properties file to change it and it works fine the but is I need to change it then build the app. Which isn't going to work in a production environment.

Is there any way to do this using an external properties file?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to have a `Configuration API` which is invoked before mount of app component and get the details of environment settings you want.

In general env variable file are meant to be changed before any build. If your settings are changing frequently then it should be part of `Configuration API` response.